# AWS: RDS + CloudFormation – VPC peering

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

So here's my situation:
We are a young startup scaling up and we decided to give Mesosphere DCOS Community edition a try. The community edition deploys a stack of Masters, Slaves and LB's over AWS CloudFormation using a template. ([our template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bcxy43hdsd6gfi/dcos_template.json?dl=0))
(editing the template to use an existing VPC causes an error: Template validation error: Template format error: `Unresolved resource dependencies [<target_vpc_id>] in the Resources block of the template`)

The community edition has two limits (I can't seem to find where these limits are documented):

- it cannot be deployed over an existing VPC.
- it creates a single-AZ VPC for each new deployment.

Now, we'd like to enable this new cluster to speak to the RDS. Obviously, we run into problems:

- The RDS instance cannot be deployed over a single-AZ VPC
- The RDS VPC can be peered to the DCOS VPC, but since RDS instances only have an endpoint (no static IP), that has to be resolved from the other VPC to a local address and not the global IP.

What would be the best way to approach this situation?

EDIT:
So, I added a private-only RDS instance and it's endpoint now correctly resolves to its local IP address from anywhere. Now, my DCOS cluster is located in a VPC which is `10.0.0.0/16` lets call this `VPC-A`, and my RDS instance is in `VPC-B`, which is `172.31.0.0/16`.

Now to enable communications between the two networks, I added a VPC peering between `VPC-A` and `VPC-B`.

Next, I set up the routes in `VPC-B` as:
Destination: 10.0.0.0/16
Targent: `<vpc_peering_id>`

And in `VPC-A` as:
Destination: 172.31.0.0/16
Target: `<vpc_peering_id>`

Security group setting for the target RDS Instance in `VPC-B`
Inbound All Traffic All ports CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16

Security group settings for source instances in `VPC-A`:
Outbound: All Traffic All Ports CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0

But then again, I still cannot make any connections from `VPC-A` to `VPC-B`.

I've also checked the security group settings for all instances belonging to `VPC-A`: All outbound traffic is allowed.
And in `VPC-B`: All incoming traffic from `10.0.0.0/16` is allowed on port `3306`.

What's going on here?

Comment: The hostname of the endpoint of a private-only-accessible RDS instance will resolve to the internal address from anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you for replying, Michael. I tried what you said but it seems like now I resolve it to the correct local ip address but I still cannot make connections to the server. Please see the edit I've made to the question. I'd appreciate any input about this.

Comment: You mentioned setting the security group for VPC-A Outbound traffic as 0.0.0.0/0, but be sure that Inbound traffic allows at least the subnet that VPC-B contains (172.31.0.0/16).

Comment: it does. By the way, I've given up on the idea based on `VPC Peering`